# Preseeding Ubuntu with primary partitions

Tags: ubuntu

I'm attempting to preseed a Xenial image and it works just fine, aside from the partitioning. cloud-init can only grow the root partition, and that doesn't work when the image is built with the root filesystem inside of an extended partition:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0      11:0    1  382K  0 rom  
xvda    202:0    0   60G  0 disk 
├─xvda1 202:1    0  1.9G  0 part /
├─xvda2 202:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─xvda5 202:5    0  2.1G  0 part
```

My partman recipe currently looks like this:

```
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string        \
  all-root ::                            \
    1 1 1 free                           \
    method{ biosgrub }                   \
    .                                    \
    750 1000 2000 ext4                   \
    $primary{ } $bootable{ }             \
    mountpoint{ / }                      \
    method{ format } format{ }           \
    use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
    .
```

I cannot for the life of me see a way of just ending up with xvda1 by itself - is there anything obscure in the docs I may have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my problem here seems to be related to the fact that I was making the biosgrub partition - this wasn't actually necessary and it was causing the installer to create an extended partition by default. I now create a single partition which behaves exactly as expected.